# I want to reverse direction of animation on my SVG

Tags: css, css-animations, svg-animate

I have this codepen animation: [Codepen SVG Testing](https://codepen.io/Blumenkranz/pen/QWwKJPq)

```
.anim {
  width:500px;
  height:281.25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 svg {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  stroke-width:10px;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-dasharray: 10000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 10000;
  animation: dash 3s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
 }
}
```

and my HTML:

```
 <div class="anim">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" enable-background="new 0 0 1920 1080" xml:space="preserve">
   <path fill="none" d="M0,392.306V1080h1920V647.331c0,0-165.5,91.836-384.623,105.011
c-215.715,12.97-302.606-198.286-324.033-252.025c-20.759-52.064-258.025-465.046-591.059-24.002c0,0-150.015,249.024-396.04-24.002
C224.246,452.312,150.792,368.303,0,392.306z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The animation starts on the top left corner to bottom (forwards).

I want it to start on the same top left, but moving to the right direction, where the waves are, then move to right bottom, then left bottom, then top left and finish.

I've tried animation-direction: reverse; but it just do the same thing but backwards.
I need to do this only with css.
What am I missing?

Comment: Do you try "alternate" instead of "reverse" or "forwards" ?

Comment: Yes, and not the result i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution. Just change the value on

```
stroke-dashoffset: 10000;
```

to

```
stroke-dashoffset: -10000;
```

Comment: I am glad you figured this out. I just saw your post and was about to answer it. It would have been the same exact answer. I am actually surprised it was not answered in a day. SO is starting to concern me.

Comment: Thank you! it was suggestive actually

Comment: This does actually not work on Safari for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit more complex, but works also in Safari for iOS.

```
@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 20000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 10000;
  }
}
```